# Count sub word frequency in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, count, frequency

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` with 2 columns that contains the type of alcohol (i.e VODKA 80 PROOF, CANADIAN WHISKIES, SPICED RUM) and the number of bottles sold. I would like to first categorize it in categories that are less granular i.e (WHISKEY, VODKA, RUM) and then sum all bottles sold per category.

My code does not allow me to isolate tags such as "VODKA" but instead returns the frequency of categories such "VODKA 80 Proof".

#### In:

```
top_N = 10 # top 10 most used categories

word_dist = nltk.FreqDist(df['Category Name'])

print('All frequencies:')
print('=' * 60)
rslt = pd.DataFrame(word_dist.most_common(top_N),
                    columns=['Word', 'Frequency'])
print(rslt)
print('=' * 60)

df= df.groupby('Category Name')['Bottles Sold'].sum()
```

#### Out:

```
All frequencies:
============================================================
                               Word  Frequency
0                    VODKA 80 PROOF      35373
1                 CANADIAN WHISKIES      27087
2         STRAIGHT BOURBON WHISKIES      15342
3                        SPICED RUM      14631
4                    VODKA FLAVORED      14001
5                           TEQUILA      12109
6                  BLENDED WHISKIES      11547
7                   WHISKEY LIQUEUR      10902
8                    IMPORTED VODKA      10668
9  PUERTO RICO & VIRGIN ISLANDS RUM      10062
============================================================
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered adding categories of matched words?  Something like:

#### Code:

```
categories = {'VODKA', 'WHISKIES', 'RUM', 'TEQUILA', 'LIQUEUR'}
df['category'] = df['product'].apply(lambda x:
                                     [c for c in categories if c in x]
```

#### Test Code:

```
data = [
    ['VODKA 80 PROOF', '35373'],
    ['CANADIAN WHISKIES', '27087'],
    ['STRAIGHT BOURBON WHISKIES', '15342'],
    ['SPICED RUM', '14631'],
    ['VODKA FLAVORED', '14001'],
    ['TEQUILA', '12109'],
    ['BLENDED WHISKIES', '11547'],
    ['WHISKEY LIQUEUR', '10902'],
    ['IMPORTED VODKA', '10668'],
    ['PUERTO RICO & VIRGIN ISLANDS RUM', '10062'],
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['product', 'count'], dtype=int)

categories = {'VODKA', 'WHISKIES', 'RUM', 'TEQUILA', 'LIQUEUR'}
df['category'] = df['product'].apply(lambda x:
                                     [c for c in categories if c in x][0])
print(df)
print(df.groupby('category')['count'].sum())
```

#### Results:

```
                            product  count  category
0                    VODKA 80 PROOF  35373     VODKA
1                 CANADIAN WHISKIES  27087  WHISKIES
2         STRAIGHT BOURBON WHISKIES  15342  WHISKIES
3                        SPICED RUM  14631       RUM
4                    VODKA FLAVORED  14001     VODKA
5                           TEQUILA  12109   TEQUILA
6                  BLENDED WHISKIES  11547  WHISKIES
7                   WHISKEY LIQUEUR  10902   LIQUEUR
8                    IMPORTED VODKA  10668     VODKA
9  PUERTO RICO & VIRGIN ISLANDS RUM  10062       RUM

category
LIQUEUR     10902
RUM         24693
TEQUILA     12109
VODKA       60042
WHISKIES    53976
Name: count, dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input Stephen!

I've done a slight modification cause your answer was returning me an KeyError.
Here is my modification:

```
def search_brand(x):
    x = str(x)
    list_brand = ['VODKA','WHISKIES', 'RUM', 'TEQUILA', 'LIQUEUR', 'BRANDIES', 'COCKTAILS']
    for word in list_brand:
        if word in x:
            return word


df['Broad Category'] = df['Category Name'].apply(search_brand)
```